# Animation jump when collapsing

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, xhtml

Help!

Take a look at [this](http://www.phsoregon.org/newsletters/eneuro/_upcoming/clinical-trials/) in IE7. When you click one of the main header it expands without a jump, but when collapsing, just as it finishes it does a little jump. I want to get rid of said jump..

Thank you

**UPDATED**

Best fix is the unseen fix that solves all issues, that is..

```
.trials * {
    border: 1px transparent solid;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what is causing this - may be the table layout of the site (when i removed the surround the code worked fine). I have cobbled together this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gNLUa/4/) of the site. In the CSS section is the fix which is working on my machine. Basically give the animating container a border. IE likes borders...

I've made the borders white so they don't appear. Reckon this should do as a single browser fix. If not hopefully it gets you on the right track!

:)

Comment: Wow wow wow, exceptional work! thank you. See my edited question for more info.

Comment: Cool, glad it helped :). Didn't realise it would work with a color value of transparent - will be trying that out in future. Thanks for posting your solution!

Answer (score 1):

IE liking borders would make me think it's a collapsing margin issue, and the border is stopping margins collapsing... but I can't see any margins on your show/hide content.

Perhaps it's the padding then, the 10px padding on the .trial div there - because that's the last thing that's seen when getting rolled up/down, perhaps IE7 doesn't know how to 'roll up' the padding, so it's hiding it in one hit, causing the jump?

Possibly try changing the padding so it's 20px bottom on the .intro div instead of 10px on each of .trial and .intro, just to see if that fixes the problem.

(note: I don't have IE7 installed so I can't see the jump you're talking about, feel free to tell me I'm on entirely the wrong track.)